# Product bundles that iclude other products in Shopify

Tags: shopify, product

I looked everywhere for an app that does product bundles correctly but i can't find it ! for example i create a product Z that contains other products X and Y !

you can see the screen below :

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C3su.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: If you need to include images, please do it directly.

Comment: No ! i need to have selector for both products in the bundles! so that customers can choose the sizes of each product inside the bundle

Comment: Couldn't you have a main product (Z), then have X and Y as variant options on that product?

Comment: I don't think so , because the X and Y products are products by themselves and i need their inventory to be calculated ... the image above shows an example that i did integrate in Magento

Comment: Ahh I see - perhaps an app like this then? https://apps.shopify.com/product-bundles

Comment: I made the first Bundling App in Shopify that allows a merchant to build a bundle and sell it with complete control. You each product in the bundle, and set the amount of the variant from the product that makes the bundle. So a bundle product may have 6 of SKU **abcd** and 4 of SKU **zzxxyy** etc. You give the bundle a price. The App then takes care of inventory once the order is received.

Comment: Also our app does it: https://apps.shopify.com/shopify-assistant